# retain state not working in android

Tags: android

I have two different layouts for activity like layout-land layout-port, with different design. I had given below code but state is maintain but potrait design is coming in landscape mode. Can anybody tell me how to avoid this? Can anybody provide sample code?

I have mention android:configChanges="orientation"

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("bufferedPercentage", video.getBufferPercentage());
    commentWebView.saveState(outState);


    //Toast.makeText(this, "Activity state saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



if(savedInstanceState!=null)
{
     commentWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `android:configChanges="orientation"` and dont mention any `screen orientation` also.

This will work

Hope it helps.